# Labeling in QGIS: what does the priority bar under "position"

Tags: qgis, labeling

when you label a layer in QGIS, under the tab "position" at the very bottom, you can set the priority from low to high.

[image]

I can't find in the documentation what it does. What is beeing prioritized?

Sorry if it is in the docs, but I don't find it.

Comment: If there is a collision and labels would overlap, the label with higher priority will be rendered.

Comment: The [PAL](http://pal.heig-vd.ch/) optimization algorithm is not easy to manually handle, but in some cases you can put one candidate over the other in a conflict. In the docs, it is in the last paragraph of [_Placement tab_](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#placement-tab). You can find an example in the [North Road's feature announce blog entry](https://north-road.com/2015/07/20/recent-labelling-improvements-in-qgis-master/)

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I would create and answer from your comment. It answers the question pretty well.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto, The optimization algorithm I think comes from the operations research discipline. The question seems very basic, but personally, I don't think I have enough understanding of the algorithm to answer it properly. My solutions to labelling was allways very specific to each situation. If I had to say exactly how priority influences labeling, I honestly wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: The relationship between priority and rendering is not so direct. I faced cases in which an entity with a higher priority was not labeled. That is why I would prefer a better answer than I could give.